# Packing Callback to normal function

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback

I need cover some callback function from library to single-thread app. I call the method `homerSendJsonMessage` several times and it is important to do it one by one. Always wait for the previous one. It's like a builder.

I have in the library callback functions - but when I put them into my method, JavaScript performed all at once. (I know why) and I think this example could have solved it. But "IDE" say - that no return values.. Any Advice?

```
public sendJson(request:YodaJsonMessage):YodaJsonMessage|Error {
    lib.homerSendJsonMessage(request, (message:YodaJsonMessage, error:any) => {
        if (!message) {
            return error;
        } else {
            return message;
        }
    });
}
```

Command from library

```
homerSendJsonMessageToYoda(message:YodaJsonMessage, callback:((message:YodaJsonMessage, error:any)=>void)):void;
```

Comment: The IDE is right, you define that the method returns `YodaJsonMessage | Error` but the function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I know  - but how can i solved that?

Comment: What does `lib.homerSendJsonMessage` return? Also, javascript is always single threaded.

Comment: its a void and you can see **Command from library**

Comment: And i Need 

1)Send  first JSON and by responses  doing something.
2) Send secong JSON and by second and first responses do something
3) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `sendJson` method is using an async function you can't return a value before the async operation has completed.
You can do:

(1) Use a callback:

```
public sendJson(request: YodaJsonMessage, cb: (result: YodaJsonMessage | Error) => void): void {
    lib.homerSendJsonMessage(request, (message: YodaJsonMessage, error: any) => {
        if (!message) {
            cb(error);
        } else {
            cb(message);
        }
    });
}
```

(2) Return a promise:

```
public sendJson(request: YodaJsonMessage): Promise<YodaJsonMessage> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        lib.homerSendJsonMessage(request, (message: YodaJsonMessage, error: any) => {
            if (!message) {
                reject(error);
            } else {
                resolve(message);
            }
        });
    });
}
```